# The problem of getting and working with dates in Js

Tags: javascript, datetime

When working with the task, it became necessary to get dates from html, and to find out the time difference between them:

```
var now_time_div = document.getElementById("time_now_of");
var start_time_div = document.getElementById("time_when_start_of");

var time_now = now_time_div.textContent || now_time_div.innerHTML;
var time_start = start_time_div.textContent || start_time_div.innerHTML;
```

After that, without thinking about the format of the data, I wanted to find the time difference in ms:

```
var worked_time = time_now - time_start
```

That didn't work, because we are working with a string.
After entering the directory, I found the Date.parse() function, which returns the amount of time that has passed since the given date:

```
var worked_time = Date.parse(time_start);
```

but it turned out that it works only with a correctly submitted strig, for example
We need to have:

```
Date.parse('01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
```

We have:

```
Date.parse('21.09.2022, 15:34:21')
```

Maybe someone knows an easy way to implement this without rebuilding the string?

Comment: ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ) is the only date format explicitly specified to be supported, though most browsers seem to support a wide range of alternatives. Question:  What is the source of the dates in the html, i.e., is this is user input or generated by the server or a script?

Comment: It is generated on the site with which the program should work

Comment: @yogi—there are [two others](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-date.parse): the formats produced by *toString* and *toUTCString*. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to bring in a library like moment.js, you can just massage the date string a bit so it can be parsed correctly

```
const dateString = '21.09.2022, 15:34:21';
const curDate = dateString.split(',')[0].substring(0, 10).split('.');
const curTime = dateString.split(',')[1];
const parsed = `${curDate[1]}'/'${curDate[0]}'/'${curDate[2]} ${curTime}`;
console.log(new Date(parsed).toString()); // Properly formatted date
```

You can used this `parsed` variable to compare to other properly formatted dates

Comment: This substitutes one unsupported format with another. If you’re going to parse the string, do it properly and either generate a supported format or pass the values for year, month, day, etc. directly to the constructor (which is preferable to parsing twice).

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js to parse custom date formats just as in for example Java:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

After that you can simply convert it to a js date using the toDate function: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/

Edit Example:

```
var mDate = moment('2022-09-21 10:15:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var jsDate = mDate.toDate();
```